# "It includes how to" is this expression grammatically right?

Tags: word-usage

this professor is [saying](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE?t=50)

> It includes **how to** collect your data, how to label your data, ...

is this expression grammatically right?

or following is more appropriate?

> It includes collecting your data, labeling your data, ...

or both work well?

Comment: The two sentences can be both correct, with different meanings, depending on the context and depending on the rest of the sentence. Please provide us with a bigger sample of the dialogue - by editing the question.

Comment: I already provided the full context by adding a link in the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both are technically correct in every day use.

From the video you provided (I only listened briefly) it sounds like he is listing a course names and therefore he is correct to use the full name of the course.

> It includes: How to collect your data; How to label your data; ..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And which one is easier to understand? Considering they are in a classroom and there is no punctuation to help to get lecturer's point.

Comment: The way he did it in the video was correct, he was listing course names